# how can i return a string with jQuery from an input and write it to a different html element

Tags: jquery, input, element

I am using this:

```
var title = $('#input').val();
$('#titleset').click(function (){
    $('#title').html('<h1>' + title + '</h1>'); 
    alert(title);
});
```

to try to get the value of an `input` box and then when the user clicks the button `#titleset`, overwrite the value from the input box to the `<h1>` element that is already there.
i have been able to get the click to overwrite the `<h1>` element, but there is nothing in the title variable to write into the element. so how could i return a string from the `#input` id and write it to the #title id which is an `<h1>` element

here is my html

```
<h1 id="title">This Title Changes To What You Want It To Be</h1>
<ul class="menu1">
    <li>menu one
        <ul>
            <li id='inputbox'><input type ="text" id="input"/></li>
            <li id="titleset1"><input type="button" value="set title" id="titleset"/></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please post the html code as well

Comment: when is the value of input defined?  when this code executes, is the #input input value undefined? you should put a quick check in the click event handler to test for value in  title.  i was able to get your code to work in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/wbq9A/   without understanding the context in which title is define, there's no way to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the input's value within the click handler:

```
$('#titleset').click(function (){
    var title = $('#input').val();
    $('#title').html('<h1>' + title + '</h1>'); 
    alert(title);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use like this:

```
$('#titleset').click(function (){
    $('#title').html('<h1>' + $('#input').val()+ '</h1>'); 
    alert(title);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

***Jquery code***

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#titleset').click(function (){
        $('h1').html($('#input').val());
    });
});
</script>
```

***Html code***

```
<h1>hello</h1>
<input name="" id="input" type="text" value="VALUE"/>
<input name="titleset" id="titleset" type="button" value="CLICK"/>
```

Comment: if it helped you please tick it as correct answer and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

This is too simple (*just three lines of code*). Try this:

```
$('#titleset').click(function() {
    $('#title').html($('#input').val());
});​
```